# Deep queries with mongodb driver in phoenix/elixir

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using the mongodb driver from https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb to query a mongodb database in an elixir/phoenix project. A simple query such as

```
cursor = Mongo.find(:mongo, "posts",%{})
      list = Enum.to_list(cursor)
      object= Enum.fetch(list,0)
      object= elem(object, 1) 
      new_list=Map.fetch(object, "name")
      new_list=elem(new_list,1)
      new_cursor= Mongo.find(:mongo, "posts",%{"name" => new_list})
      new_list=Enum.to_list(new_cursor)
```

is no problem, but I am wondering how to perform deeper searches as I have nested jsons such as

```
{"posts":{"name":"something","attributes":{"aspect":{"and_so_on":"endpoint"}}}}.
```

So how to get to "endpoint" in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is extremely not [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) idiomatic, in the first place. One should not reassign values on each step, we usually use pipes [`Kernel.|>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.10.0/Kernel.html?#%7C%3E/2) instead.

That said, your original cursor might be written as

```rb
list =
  :mongo
  |> Mongo.find("posts", %{})
  |> Enum.fetch(0)
  |> elem(1) 
  |> Map.fetch("name")
  |> elem(1)
new_list =
  :mongo
  |> Mongo.find("posts", %{"name" => list})
  |> Enum.to_list()
```

or, better, with pattern matching

```rb
%{"name" => one} =
  Mongo.find_one(:mongo, "posts", %{})
one
#⇒ "something"
```

---

MongoDB also supports [mongo query language](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document) in [`Mongo.find/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/mongodb/Mongo.html#find/4) as shown in [examples here](https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb#examples). To get to the nested element one might do:

```rb
Mongo.find(:mongo, "posts",
  %{"attributes" => %{"aspect" => "and_so_on"}})
```